# Functions: A good condition

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Suppose a sub-set $A$ of a set $E$. Now, suppose an application $f$ defined as: $f : A \to \overline{A}$.

We defined $\mathcal{G_f}$, the graph of the application $f$ (it's a sub-set of the cartesian product: $A\times \overline{A}$).

> Find a necessary condition such that the reunion of all elements of $\mathcal{G_f}$ is equal to the set $E$ (in another words a condition which satisfies: $(\operatorname{pr}_1 \mathcal{G_f})\ \cup\ (\operatorname{pr}_2 \mathcal{G_f}) = E$, where $\operatorname{pr_1}$ is the reunion of every first element of all couples of $\mathcal{G_f}$ and $\operatorname{pr_2}$, the reunion of every second element of all couples of $\mathcal{G_f}$).

Comment: What is $\overline A$ in this scenario? What do you mean by "a good condition"? Are you selling a function in a good condition? Because I only buy mint condition functions.

Comment: $\pi_1[G_f] = A$ by definition, isn't it?

Comment: And if $\overline{A}$ is the complement of $A$ in $E$, you need $f$ to be surjective and then $\pi_2[G_f] = \overline{A}$ and combined with the previous remark, $\pi_1[G_f] \cup \pi_2[G_f] = E$.

Comment: Are you translating this question from some language other than English? Writing "application" where you mean "function" or "map", and "reunion" where you mean (hmm, perhaps just "set"), is definitely not standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $\overline{A}$ is the complement of $A$ in $E$:

As $f$ is a function defined by on $A$ to $\overline{A}$, we know that:

$$\pi_1[G_f] = A \text{ and } \pi_2[G_f] \subseteq \overline{A}$$.

So $\pi_1[G_f] \cup \pi_2[G_f] = E$ iff $\pi_2[G_f] = \overline{A}$ iff $f$ is surjective (onto). So we need at least that $|\overline{A}| \le |A|$ in order for such an $f$ to be able to exist.